# 1004 ODBC General Error when columns are added to a query

Tags: excel, vba, amazon-redshift

Original Query that works

```
CSQL2 = CSql1 & vbNewLine & _
          "SELECT CASE WHEN TRIM ( y.fbn ) LIKE '%ABC%' THEN ( bd.build_id ) ELSE TRIM ( y.fbn ) END AS fbn, y.number, y.title, y.owner, y.type, y.open_closed," & vbNewLine & _
          "y.date_approved, y.date_submitted_for_approval, y.expires_after, y.status, y.reg," & vbNewLine & _
          "y.site, y.lines, y.cap, y.committed, y.invoiced, CASE" & vbNewLine & _
          "WHEN y.Lines = 'Electrical' THEN 'Electrical_Equipment'" & vbNewLine & _
          "WHEN y.Lines = 'Mechanical' THEN 'Mechanical_Equipment'" & vbNewLine & _
          "WHEN y.Lines = 'Construction' THEN 'Base'" & vbNewLine & _
          "ELSE y.Lines END category, " & vbNewLine & _
          "CASE WHEN y.Lines = 'Electrical' THEN 'Other' " & vbNewLine & _
          "WHEN y.Lines = 'Mechanical' THEN 'Other' " & vbNewLine & _
          "WHEN y.Lines = 'Construction' THEN 'Base' ELSE y.Lines " & vbNewLine & _
          "END subcategory " & vbNewLine & _
          "FROM s1.line_new y LEFT JOIN (SELECT build_id, fbn FROM bd) bd ON bd.fbn = y.fbn " & vbNewLine & _
          "WHERE Lines <> 'NW' AND ( y.Cap <> 0 OR y.Committed <> 0 OR y.Invoiced <> 0 )" & vbNewLine & _
          "AND y.fbn IN ( SELECT DISTINCT fbn FROM bd )" & vbNewLine & _
          "AND y.number NOT IN (SELECT num FROM s1.att) AND" & vbNewLine & CARFilters
```

New query that doesn't work to refresh the list object:

```
CSql2 = CSql1 & vbNewLine & _
          "SELECT CASE WHEN TRIM ( bd.fbn ) LIKE '%ABC%' THEN ( bd.build_id ) ELSE TRIM ( bd.fbn ) END AS fbn, y.number, y.title, y.owner, y.type, y.open_closed," & vbNewLine & _
          "y.date_approved, y.date_submitted_for_approval, y.expires_after, y.status, y.reg," & vbNewLine & _
          "y.site, y.lines, ROUND(SUM(y.capex) OVER ( PARTITION BY y.fbn, lines ),2) AS cap, y.committed, y.invoiced, CASE" & vbNewLine & _
          "WHEN y.Lines = 'Electrical' THEN 'Electrical_Equipment'" & vbNewLine & _
          "WHEN y.Lines = 'Mechanical' THEN 'Mechanical_Equipment'" & vbNewLine & _
          "WHEN y.Lines = 'Construction' THEN 'Base'" & vbNewLine & _
          "ELSE y.Lines END category, " & vbNewLine & _
          "CASE WHEN y.Lines = 'Electrical' THEN 'Other' " & vbNewLine & _
          "WHEN y.Lines = 'Mechanical' THEN 'Other' " & vbNewLine & _
          "WHEN y.Lines = 'Construction' THEN 'Base' ELSE y.Car_Lines " & vbNewLine & _
          "END subcategory  ,mcl.currency_id mcl_currency ,fx_2.local_currency ,fx_2.conversion_rate 2_fx_rate " & vbNewLine & _
          ",mcl.exchange_rate_effective_date,ROUND(fx.rate,4) conversion_rate " & vbNewLine & _
          ",ROUND(SUM(y.cap*fx.rate) OVER ( PARTITION BY y.fbn, lines ),2) AS cap_local " & vbNewLine & _
          "FROM s1.mcl_carline_new y LEFT JOIN (SELECT build_id, fbn FROM bd) bd ON bd.fbn = y.fbn " & vbNewLine & _
          "LEFT JOIN (SELECT number, exchange_rate_effective_date, currency_id FROM s1.mcl_new) mcl ON y.number = mcl.number " & vbNewLine & _
          "LEFT JOIN s1.fx_rate_2 fx_2 ON fx_2.reg = y.reg " & vbNewLine & _
          "LEFT JOIN s2.prcmt_exchange_rate fx ON fx_2.local_currency = fx.to_currency_id " & vbNewLine & _
          "AND mcl.currency_id = fx.from_currency_id AND mcl.exchange_rate_effective_date = fx.effective_date " & vbNewLine & _
          "WHERE Lines <> 'NW' AND ( y.Cap <> 0 OR y.Committed <> 0 OR y.Invoiced <> 0 ) " & vbNewLine & _
          "AND y.fbn IN ( SELECT DISTINCT fbn FROM bd ) " & vbNewLine & _
          "AND y.number NOT IN (SELECT num FROM s1.att) AND " & vbNewLine & CARFilters
```

Listobject Refresh section

```
With CData.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=CS, Destination:=CData.Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandText = CSql2
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "CData"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
```

During this LO existed and I had to modify the query, which added some columns; this refresh worked find until the columns got added.  Now I get a 1004 General OBDC, but when I  `Debug.Print` the query and run it AS IS in my SQL client it works without issue.

How can I tell what is causing the 1004? Note - CSql1 is unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

12 hours of working on this and less than an hour after the bounty; I find the issue.  Someone had removed permissions for the user running the query on the table required to retrieve the results.

Comment: Ah.  By the way, shouldn't this be in a stored procedure?

Comment: If you have a guide of some sort on how to feed data from an excel file into Redshift with a stored procedure executed from VBA because it isn't a standard execution time; happy to see it